# create objects dynamically according database values

Tags: apache-flex

I have a  Flex project. I want to dynamically create mx.controls.Image objects and add them to the display. However, the number of images and it properties deponds on the value stored in a database. Hence, I have to connect to the database,read the values for data table, then  create objects  dynamically according the values.

Then,  I wonder if this is possible and how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Felix

Comment: You work in Flex Air? In this version is posible. The BD images is encoding? Or only have the reference path for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just try declaring a variable as *.

Like var any:*; And check always for null. So it will take any type of value.

Hope it will help.